# How to create multiple files(100 files) and they can contain 30 random characters in each of them

Tags: linux

I need to create 100 files using script Linux which contain 30 random characters password and that password contain only strings, small letters and big letters.

```
// #!/bin/bash
for n in {1..100}; do

dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/mymnt/passwords/only_numbers_and_lettersNUM.txt$( printf %03d "$n" ).bin bs=1 count=$(( RANDOM + 1024 ))

head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 30 ; echo ''

done //
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here. Please could you describe why what you've tried doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in {1..100}; do
    { < /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z | head -c${1:-30};echo; } > /mnt/mymnt/passwords/$n
done
```

Comment: Thanks gopy, but I still need the files to be created in the directory " /mnt/mymnt/passwords " and with the name " only_numbers_and_lettersNUM.txt "

Comment: @NourJandali: Then you improve the above script to suit your needs

Comment: what would you like to name the files?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am new to Linux.

Comment: " only_numbers_and_lettersNUM.txt " and also if I need to make them numbers and letters I should put A-Za-Z0-9 right?

Comment: you can use `password$n.txt` instead of `$n`.  yes that is correct